# R package help for whole package

Tags: r, r-package, roxygen2

Some packages (e.g. `base`) display a help page describing the package when the command `help("base")` or `?base` is given.

How can this be accomplished  when creating a package when `roxygen2` is used to create the documentation?

Comment: several vignettes to help get started at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roxygen2/

Answer (score 1):

See this chapter of R Packages (2e) by Hadley Wickham and Jennifer Bryan: [Documentation/Function documentation/Help topic for the package](https://r-pkgs.org/man.html#sec-man-package-doc).

> We recommend calling `usethis::use_package_doc()` to set up this package-level documentation in a dummy file `R/{pkgname}-package.R`, whose contents will look something like this:
>
> ```r
> #' @keywords internal 
> "_PACKAGE"
> ```